# Is there a way to restrict businesses (establishment) from showing up in the autocomplete at all?

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete

I'm working on a search functionality where I use Google's autocomplete javascript library to get suggestions and pass it to AwesomeComplete library to populate it nicely in a search box. One of the requirement is strictly not to show any businesses in the search prediction. Is there a way to restrict businesses from the autocomplete suggestions?

I know that we can include different types to show up on the suggestion by adding them into the types attribute. And I have already tried with setting different types other than 'establishment', but still, I'm seeing a lot of businesses for even simple keywords.

```
var googleDisplaySuggestion = function(predictions, status) {

  if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    return;
  }

  var list = predictions.map(function (prediction) {

    return {
      label: prediction.description,
      value: prediction.id,
    }
  });

  awesome.list = list; // final list being sent to awesome complete 

};

var googleList = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(44.84808025602071,-78.321533203125), 
  new google.maps.LatLng(42.93631775765237,-80.584716796875), 
);

var searchOptions = {
   input: val, // Assume the value comes from input box
   type: ['street_address','(cities)','library','airport'], // sample types other than businesses
   componentRestrictions: {country: 'ca'},
   bound: defaultBounds, 
   strictBounds: true,
   location: new google.maps.LatLng(43.753994, -79.446807), 
   radius: 50000, 
};

googleList.getPlacePredictions(searchOptions, googleDisplaySuggestion);
```

I expect to see suggestions without any businesses showing up

Answer (score 0):

you have a mistake in your `searchOptions` object for the `types` properties.
Also,  to return only geocoding results, rather than business results use `types: ['geocode']`

It should looks like:

```js
var searchOptions = {
   types: ['geocode']
};
```

However, only a single type is allowed.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#AutocompleteOptions.types

Comment: Sorry, that is a typo when I edited the code in the editor. I double-checked with my original code and this is not an issue. Also, is type should be singular or plural?

Comment: it seems to be singular. the doc says: In general only a single type is allowed. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#AutocompleteOptions.types

Comment: Do you have any other suggestion on the issue that I have? I still couldn't fix it.

Comment: use `types: ['geocode']` to return only geocoding results, rather than business results

Comment: Is there a way to add multiple types to this? I saw some resources online saying the multi-type feature has been deprecated as of February 16, 2017. The documentation is pretty confusing and I'm not sure where I can get the right information.

Comment: This is i believe related with https://issuetracker.google.com/35822178